# Keyboard/Mouse Robot not working when focused on a certain application

Tags: java, security, awtrobot

So I am trying to use a robot (either keypress or mouse) to simulate some tests on an application. However, this program isn't allowing me to do so and I'm pretty sure it is a security feature. The application I am using is [TEMS Investigation](http://www.ascom.com/nt/en/index-nt/tems-products-3/tems-investigation-5.htm) and I am trying to simulate a record and stop recording for some automated tests I have. The program I am using to automate these tests can not access TEMS so there is no way for me to do this without a Robot. So my questions are:

1) How can I override whatever it is that is preventing me from using my robot.
2) Would this be considered illegal if I did? I don't need to break any laws...I just want to get my testing done! lol

I can't even runs something as simple as:

```
Robot r = new Robot();

r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F2);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F2);
```

It will run, as I have downloaded some software to tell me what keys I am pressing....just wont be recognized while the TEMS application has focus.

> Update: I found out using Notepad I can't use any keys (like "ALT +
>   F") to perform any menu options. It doesn't even pull up the "File"
>   menu. I am able to simulate typing in text, just not the context menu.
>   What was really weird is that I can't even use mouseMove() while TEMS
>   has the focus

Comment: Illegal how? My impression is Robot is meant for stuff like this and you shouldn't need to hack anything to do something as simple as send key presses to native. It could be the TEMS application is ignoring the input somehow unless it comes from a device. Some of the related SO questions over there `->` may have some answers for you. Maybe somebody who has experience using Robot (I don't) can tell you better though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your runtime has no knowledge of the TEMS app. If you start it in your java code it should work. For example the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad");
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_J);
```

Will bring up notepad and type in the letter J. Try exec-ing TEMS and then send the key press.

And no, it's not illegal.

UPDATE:

To open the file menu in notepad, you would do the following:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
```

The two keys must be `pressed` together before a `robot.keyRelease`.

Comment: Does the TEMS app run full screen? Hard to guess what could be wrong or if they wrote something to block it

Comment: Update: I found out using Notepad I can't use any keys (like "ALT + F") to perform any menu options. It doesn't even pull up the "File" menu. I am able to simulate typing in text, just not the context menu. What was really weird is that I can't even use `mouseMove()` while TEMS has the focus.

Comment: Updated answer with example of opening file menu.

Comment: Yea, that is exactly what I am trying to do....`robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F); robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);`, but I am not able to get to any menu items...even in notepad. So this seems to be my issue now...I can't get the menu items, such as "File" to open. I used an application to confirm that the right keys are being sent and they are.